# spring boot & thymeleaf

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I use spring boot 1.5.6 release, and thymeleaf 3.0.0.release, thymeleaf-layout-dialect 2.0.0.

I wrote a html file, like below.
[image]

header_top and footer_bottom are another two html files, contents are:
[image]

[image]

and I have a controller, it is very simple:

[image]

The start application are as below:

[image]

```
the applications.properties file cotains contents below: 
spring.thymeleaf.mode=HTML5
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
spring.session.store-type=none

logging.level.root=INFO
logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG
debug=true
```

When I run the app, I put http://localhost:8080 in the chrome address bar. What I got is hello world. So I guess the spring boot & thymeleaf template resolver can find the index.html file. But the `header_top::catelog` and `footer_bottom::copy` are not parsed at all. I checked the source code of the page through the chrome dev tools. the `<div th:insert...` are just as it is in the template files. So I guess the `th:*` are not parsed at all. I am new to spring boot and thymeleaf. I have googled for a long time, but still cannot find a solution.

Please anyone help me.

When request happens, the logs are as follows:

`2017-08-25 10:56:35.023 DEBUG 34177 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.b.w.f.OrderedRequestContextFilter    : Bound request context to thread: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@6333b70f
2017-08-25 10:56:35.024 DEBUG 34177 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/]
2017-08-25 10:56:35.024 DEBUG 34177 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /
2017-08-25 10:56:35.024 DEBUG 34177 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Returning handler method [public java.lang.String com.easylife.haozu.controller.IndexController.index(org.springframework.ui.Model)]
2017-08-25 10:56:35.024 DEBUG 34177 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Last-Modified value for [/] is: -1
2017-08-25 10:56:35.024 DEBUG 34177 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Requested media types are [text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/webp, image/apng, application/xml;q=0.9, */*;q=0.8] based on Accept header types and producible media types [*/*])
2017-08-25 10:56:35.024 DEBUG 34177 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.w.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver  : No matching bean found for view name 'index'
2017-08-25 10:56:35.025 DEBUG 34177 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Returning [org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView@64c00234] based on requested media type 'text/html'
2017-08-25 10:56:35.025 DEBUG 34177 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Rendering view [org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView@64c00234] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
2017-08-25 10:56:35.028 DEBUG 34177 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Successfully completed request
2017-08-25 10:56:35.028 DEBUG 34177 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.b.w.f.OrderedRequestContextFilter    : Cleared thread-bound request context: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@6333b70f`

Comment: This might not be the issue, but, is it per specs for you to have the open and closed `html`, `body` and `Doctype` tags inside the header and footer files, factoring that you already have them in the main index?

Comment: @andre3wap that is not the problem because the piece of code inserted is only the one inside the th:fragment

Answer (score 0):

Could you try the insert in this way?

`<div th:insert="header_top :: catalog"></div>`

`<div th:insert="footer_bottom :: copy"></div>`

Also, the th namespace in header_top.html is incorrect, it should be:

`xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"`

And could be great if you remove the unused xmlns:layout, just in case.

Comment: The w3c namespace is suggested by the intelij idear IDE(2017.2 ultimate edition). I have tried what you said before I posted this question, still the problem.

Comment: Did you removed the ~ character from the th:insert? Did you tried removing this 3 chars ~{}? So instead of <div th:insert="~{header_top :: catalog}"></div> you will have <div th:insert="header_top :: catalog"></div>

Answer (score 0):

Try to insert your fragments like this:

```
 <div th:replace="components/header_top :: catalog"></div>
 <div th:replace="components/footer_bottom :: copy"></div>
```

Where **components/header_top** and **components/footer_bottom** stand for paths to your HTML fragment files (it should be placed for example in **templates** folder of your application)

**catalog** and **copy** after **::** are your fragments names (should be the same as your th:fragment names).

Comment: Still the problem :(

Comment: What the log of application says then?